# How do I get the parent entity in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I create a "Post" entity via the following line:

```
    post = Post(date=datetime.now(),title=postInfo['title'],body=postInfo['body'],postid=postIdForTitle(postInfo['title']),parent=author)
```

where `author` is a datastore entity.

How do I access a "post"'s parent? I tried doing `post.parent` but apparently "parent" is a function. I was unable to find this in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a key of a parent entity from the key of your child entity. Look at the key Class:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_parent

Comment: Thanks much for the answer. How do I query using the key though? EDIT: Hm, I didn't even have to query the key to get the entity, it just worked... how is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
key_name = postIdForTitle(postInfo['title'])
parent = post.get_by_key_name(key_name).parent
```